# Are Landau levels always degenerate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, geometry

Solving the [Landau problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization), namely the quantum mechanical problem of a particle in a magnetic field leads to degenerate energy states, the famous Landau levels. My question consists of two parts.

1. Are these states infinitely degenerate?
2. What happens when are geometry is not a plane but we try solving the problem on a sphere or on a hyperbolic plane instead? Are the corresponding Landau levels (infinitely) degenerate in all cases?

Any relevant pointers to the literature would be very helpful.

Comment: What is meant with "on the sphere or on a hyperbolic plane", do you mean the electrons are bound to such a geometry with a binding force much larger than the magnetic energy (even then they will not be sharply located)? Or do you mean an inhomogeneous magnetic field?

Comment: I mean the background geometry is such. Namely the electron is bound to be moving on the surface of a sphere or a hyperbolic plane